# Función recursiva constexpr usando if constexpr e if tradicional

Tags: c++, c++1z, constexpr

Usando gcc (HEAD 7.0.0 201612) me encontré con la sorpresa de que esto funciona:

```
constexpr long value(const char *definition)
{
    if (definition && *definition)
    {
        return *definition + value(definition + 1);
    }

    return *definition;
}

int main()
{
    long l{};
    std::cin >> l;

    switch (l)
    {
        case value("AAAA"): f1(); break;
        case value("BBBB"): f2(); break;
        default: error();         break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Los literales de cadena `"AAAA"` y `"BBBB"` son tratados como valores en tiempo de compilación y las llamadas a `value` devuelven los valores `260` y `264` respectivamente.

La función constexpr `value` es usada en un contexto en que sólo se aceptan valores conocidos en tiempo de compilación: en la cláusula `case` de un `switch`, así que estaba esperando que el compilador se quejase con un mensaje de error parecido a "*las cadenas de caracteres no son expresiones constantes*". De hecho es lo que sucede si se llama `value` con un valor no conocido en tiempo de compilación:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    long l{};
    std::cin >> l;

    switch (l)
    {
        case value("AAAA"): f1();    break;
        case value("BBBB"): f2();    break;
        case value(*argv):  error(); break; // Error de compilacion!
        default: error();            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Una característica de las funciones `constexpr` es que pueden ser evaluadas tanto en tiempo de compilación como en tiempo de ejecución, su evaluación es en tiempo de compilación si son llamadas con parámetros conocidos en tiempo de compilación, y este es el motivo por el que las llamadas `value("AAAA")` y `value("BBBB")` funcionan en la cláusula `case` mientras que `value(*argv)` muestra el siguiente error:

> ```
> In function 'int main(int, char**)':
> error: 'argv' is not a constant expression
>         case value(*argv):  error(); break;
>                         ^
> ```

El contenido de `*argv` no es conocido en tiempo de compilación así que se evalúa `value` en tiempo de ejecución, provocando el fallo porque la cláusula `case` requiere valores conocidos en tiempo de compilación.

Sabiendo que `value` se evalúa en tiempo de compilación, quise pasar al siguiente nivel añadiendo un `if constexpr` a la función `value`:

```
constexpr long value(const char *definition)
{
    if constexpr (definition && *definition)
    {
        return *definition + value(definition + 1);
    }

    return *definition;
}
```

Pero al hacerlo, el compilador se queja:

> ```
> In function 'constexpr long int value(const char*)':
>  error: 'definition' is not a constant expression
>      if constexpr (definition && *definition)
>                                             ^
> ```

Aparentemente el puntero `definition` no es evaluable en tiempo de compilación en el `if constexpr` pero usando un `if` tradicional toda la función `value` ¡sí que se evalúa en tiempo de compilación!.

No entiendo esta diferencia de comportamiento.

Comment: Igual digo una burrada ( en mi gcc-6 ese código no compila ) pero se me ha ocurrido una cosa: ¿ puedes declarar la función `vale( )` como `static` ? o, en su defecto, ¿ meterla en un `namespace` anónimo ? ¿ acepta entonces el `if constexr` ?

Comment: @Trauma el `if constexpr` es una característica de C++17 así que sólo está disponible en versiones *experimentales* de compiladores. [Puedes comprobar](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11) si tu gcc soporta `if constexpr` si se cumple la siguiente macro: `__cpp_if_constexpr >= 201606`.

Comment: Tu que puedes, te importaría declarar la `value( )` como  `static` o en un `namespace` anonimo y probar si admite el `if constexpr` ? No puedo comprobar una cosa en mi equipo.

Comment: @Trauma ahora mismo me viene bastante mal :( pero tú también puedes usando un [compilador online](http://melpon.org/wandbox) :)

Comment: Fijate, no tenía ni idea de que existia tal cosa. ¡ Muchas gracias por la info !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Una característica de las funciones constexpr es que pueden ser evaluadas tanto en tiempo de compilación como en tiempo de ejecución, **su evaluación es en tiempo de compilación si son llamadas con parámetros conocidos en tiempo de compilación**, y este es el motivo por el que las llamadas value("AAAA") y value("BBBB") funcionan en la cláusula case mientras que value(*argv) muestra el siguiente error:

Esa parte destacada no es correcta del todo. Lo correcto sería decir que *su evaluación **podrá realizarse en tiempo de compilación** si son llamadas con parámetros conocidos en tiempo de compilación*.

El compilador no tiene la obligación de evaluar una función `constexpr` en tiempo de compilación. Es posible, por poner un ejemplo, que la recursividad supere un límite prefijado y aborte la evaluación (dejando dicha tarea para el tiempo de ejecución).

Por otro lado, el error que comentas:

```
if constexpr (definition && *definition)
{
    return *definition + value(definition + 1);
}
```

Se produce porque `if constexpr` requiere que los términos analizados puedan ser convertidos a una expresión constante que debe devolver un booleano. En tu caso esta condición no se cumple. Puedes alegar que las llamadas que están realizando permiten conocer los valores en tiempo de compilación, pero el compilador está analizando única y exclusivamente la función `value()` y en ese contexto es imposible garantizar que `definition` sea conocida en tiempo de compilación (recordemos que `constexpr` no garantiza que la función vaya a ser evaluada **siempre** en tiempo de compilación).

Para verificar que lo que digo es verdad, vamos a modificar ligeramente la función:

```
constexpr long value(const char* definition)
{
    constexpr char* val = "AAAA";
    if constexpr (val && *val)
    {
        return *definition + value(definition + 1);
    }

    return *definition;
}
```

Ahora la función (compilada en clag 3.9.0 con -std=c++1z) sí será capaz de compilar porque el compilador puede estar seguro de que `val` es conocida en tiempo de compilación (saldrán algunos warnings pero no es significativo).

La diferencia entre usar `if` o `if constexpr` es la siguiente: Al usar `if` la sentencia se evaluará únicamente al evaluar `value()` en cada llamada (en los casos en los que sus parámetros sean conocidos en tiempo de compilación). Mientras que `if constexpr` se evalua de forma independiente y requiere la garantía de que todos los casos que se le puedan llegar a presentar sean evaluables en tiempo de compilación.

---

**EDITO**

Para demostrar que una función `constexpr` no tiene la obligación de ser evaluada en tiempo de compilación sirva el siguiente ejemplo:

```
constexpr int sum(int n)
{
  return (n>0)? n + sum(n-1) : n;
}

int func1()
{ return sum(10); }

int func2()
{ return sum(1000000); }
```

El ensamblado que se genera en gcc 6.3 compilado con -O3 es el siguiente:

```
func1():
    mov     eax, 55
    ret
func2():
    pxor    xmm1, xmm1
    xor     eax, eax
    movdqa  xmm0, XMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
    movdqa  xmm2, XMMWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
.L3:
    add     eax, 1
    paddd   xmm1, xmm0
    paddd   xmm0, xmm2
    cmp     eax, 25000
    jne     .L3
    movdqa  xmm0, xmm1
    psrldq  xmm0, 8
    paddd   xmm1, xmm0
    movdqa  xmm0, xmm1
    psrldq  xmm0, 4
    paddd   xmm1, xmm0
    movd    eax, xmm1
    ret
.LC0:
    .long   100000
    .long   99999
    .long   99998
    .long   99997
.LC1:
    .long   -4
    .long   -4
    .long   -4
    .long   -4
```

Ahí se ve como `sum(10)` se evalua perfectamente (resultado 55) y el compilador es capaz de optimizar su resultado mientras que el resultado de `sum(1000000)` se calculará en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: Si lo he entendido bién, se podria decir que ¿ cada `constexpr` *solo tienen en cuenta el nivel superior* de contexto ? Es decir, el compilador solo asciende 1 nivel en la jerarquia de llamadas para comprobar si una `constexpr` es válida o no. ¿ correcto ?

Comment: @Trauma No. Una cosa es `constexpr` y otra `if constexpr`. En el primer caso se le indica al compilador que la función es susceptible de ser evaluada en tiempo de compilación, mientras que en el segundo caso se exige que la condición sea conocida sí o sí en tiempo de compilación.

Comment: Aclarado. Por sutilezas de ese tipo es por lo que **no me gusta** el C++. Tienes mi voto.

Comment: @Trauma Para no gustarte sueles aparecer bastante en las preguntas de C++ ... :D

Comment: @eferion `constexpr` le indica al compilador que la función es **suceptible** de ser evaluada en TdC e `if constexpr` se le **exige** eso mismo. Pero en mi ejemplo se ve que toda la función, incluída la expresión del `if`, es evaluable en tiempo de compilación por lo tanto cumple con la exigencia (¿puedo cambiar las citas de tu respuesta a formato cita?)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster `if constexpr` viene con la exigencia de que la expresión **ha de ser** evaluable en tiempo de compilación, mientras que `constexpr` indica que la función **puede** ser evaluada en tiempo de compilación. Ese "_puede_" es lo que provoca que `if constexpr` no pueda garantizar la evaluación. Si fuese como dices mi ejemplo fallaría y/o tu código funcionaría.

Comment: Unnn creo que el compilador *tiene un límite* en cuantos `scope` analiza para determinar si una expresión es o no `constrexpr`. @PaperBirdMaster, si desde `value( )` lamas a otra función `constrexpr`, ¿ que pasaria ?

Comment: @Trauma no veo que pase [nada en especial](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/tBHGjGiXLNiDY941).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster he actualizado la respuesta para demostrarte que `constexpr` no implica que la función vaya a ser evaluada aun siendo sus parámetros conocidos en tiempo de compilación.