# ¿A qué se debe este error? [Error] switch quantity not an integer

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Salta este error ¿Por qué pasa esto?:

> [Error] switch quantity not an integer

Sé que se puede hacer con `if`, pero el objetivo es usar la estructura `case`.

```
char Fn_Eli() {
    cout << "Seleccione que caso desea"
    << "\n Hallar hipotenusa = 1"
    <<  "\n5 Vectorial = 2 "
    << "\nNumeros mayores = 3 "
    << "\nPor favor ingrese su opcion:" << endl;

    string opcion;
    cin >> opcion; 

    switch(opcion) {
    case 1: Fn_CalHip(); break;
    case 2: Fn_Cal5Vect(); break;
    case 3: Fn_FidMay3n(); break;
    default: cout << "Usted ha ingresado una opción incorrecta";
}
```

Comment: Que `opcion` no es de tipo integral, no puedes comparar un `string` con un `int`., prueba a cambiar `string opcion` por `int opcion`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es por que **opcion** es de tipo **string**  y debería de ser de tipo **int** para que se pueda realizar la comparación, ya que lo que está dentro de  **case 1** se ejecutaría en caso de que **opción valga** **1**.
Lo que está en **case 2** se ejecutaría en caso de que **opcion** valga **2**.

Answer (score 3):

`switch` únicamente se puede ejecutar sobre algunos tipos nativos:

- `int` y `unsigned int`
- `char` y `unsigned char`
- `short` y `unsigned short`
- `long` y `unsigned long`
- `long long` y `unsigned long long`
- enumerados (están basados en los tipos anteriores)
- `bool` (¿alguien lo usa así?)

Pero nunca sobre un tipo `string`. El motivo es que `switch` es realmente una operación de bajo nivel que no va a deducir el operador de comparación a utilizar sino que realiza una comparación directa *a pelo*. Este tipo de comparación no es compatible con tipos compuestos y de ahí que posea un uso tan restrictivo.

La gran ventaja de usar `switch` es que el compilador puede convertir las comparaciones en una tabla de desplazamientos, lo que hace que la ejecución pueda solventar el `switch` de forma rapidísma. Sustituir `switch` por cadenas de `if-else` te permitiría comparar cadenas pero entonces el compilador tendría que pasar necesariamente por toda la cadena de condicionales hasta encontrar su camino y esto consume considerablemente más tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

La estructura de control `switch` sólo permite expresiones constantes de [tipo integral](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) en sus etiquetas de control. Esto no hace que sea imposible usar cadenas en las etiquetas de control, pero complica su uso.

En otras preguntas disponibles en el sitio se han propuesto soluciones válidas para usar cadenas en `switch`, mi respuesta se basa en la combinación de:

- [Como usar correctamente un `switch case`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59375/como-usar-correctamente-un-switch-case).
- [Función recursiva `constexpr` usando `if constexpr` e `if` tradicional](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40515/funci%c3%b3n-recursiva-constexpr-usando-if-constexpr-e-if-tradicional).

---

En primer lugar definimos una función que nos traduzca en tiempo de ejecución una cadena de caracteres a un valor integral:

```
constexpr long value(const char *definition)
{
    if (definition && *definition)
    {
        return *definition + value(definition + 1);
    }

    return *definition;
}
```

Esta función `value` es una función `constexpr`, lo que significa que puede ser usada para cálculos en tiempo de compilación y/o en tiempo de ejecución pero si todos los datos proveídos a la función están disponibles en tiempo de compilación: se calculará en tiempo de compilación (más detalles en [`constexpr` desencadenadas - Vitamina C++ [image]](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2014/09/09/constexpr-desencadenadas/)).

Con esta función podemos reescribir tu `Fn_Eli` de la siguiente manera:

```
char Fn_Eli() {
    std::cout << "Seleccione que caso desea"
              << "\n Hallar hipotenusa = 1"
              <<  "\n5 Vectorial = 2 "
              << "\nNumeros mayores = 3 "
              << "\nPor favor ingrese su opcion:" << std::endl;

    std::string opcion;
    std::cin >> opcion; 

    switch(value(opcion.c_str())) {
        case value("1"): Fn_CalHip();   break;
        case value("2"): Fn_Cal5Vect(); break;
        case value("3"): Fn_FidMay3n(); break;
        default: std::cout << "Usted ha ingresado una opción incorrecta";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando En <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OQ2sjS0tu6P4NIVE)</kbd>.

Comment: Habría que mejorar esa función `value()` para que `"hola"`, `"halo"` y cualquier otra permutación posible con esas letras no devuelvan el mismo resultado y provoquen errores de compilación ;). Por todo lo demás mola lo que se puede hacer con `constexpr`

Comment: Tienes razón, he creado un hash muy tonto y con muchas colisiones, pero es sólo a nivel ilustrativo :)

Comment: Lo se, la respuesta es válida pero era por dejar constancia de ello por si alguno se pone quisquilloso y empieza  a repartir negativos