# Como usar correctamente un switch case

Tags: c++, windows

Hola normalmente puedo hacer una comprobación haciendo un if:

```
static const wchar_t *example=L"myprogram";

    if (!lstrcmpW(((LVITEMW*)lparam)->pszText, example))//The lparam is a LVITEM* struct.
            {
                return 0;
            }
```

Pero ahora quería intentar hacerlo desde un switch case..:

```
switch ( ((LVITEMW*)lparam)->pszText ) {
  case L"pro.exe":            // Note the colon, not a semicolon
    return 0;
    break;
  default:     
    break;
  }
```

Sin embargo obtengo los siguientes errores:

```
dllmain.cpp:29:40: error: switch quantity not an integer
switch ( ((LVITEMW*)lparam)->pszText ) {
^
:30:10: error: could not convert '"p\000r\000o\000.\000e\000x\000e\000\000"' from 'const wchar_t [8]' to '<type error>'
case L"pro.exe": // Note the colon, not a semicolon
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?
El problema esque tiene que ser un wchar_t porque `((LVITEMW*)lparam)->pszText )`será un wchar_t.

Comment: Me parece que para tebajar con switch debes usar un entero, no un char o un wchar_t por eso el mensaje de error te lo esta indicando `switch quantity not an integer` usualmente cuando se usa char en un switch se usa entre comillas simple, lo que lo convierte en un entero

Comment: pues me devuelve error: switch quantity not an integer
   switch ( ((LVITEMW*)lparam)->pszText ) ... supongo que todo tiene que ser entero como dijistes..

Comment: en fin un if es siempre mas facil que un switch....

Comment: mira esta [pregunta] (http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/58716/a-qu%C3%A9-se-debe-este-error-error-switch-quantity-not-an-integer)

Comment: Se puede hacer algo *parecido* a lo que quieres si estas en C++11. Pero **cuidado**, que se basa en calcular *hash* de las cadenas, y puedes tener colisiones. Mira [esto](https://dev.krzaq.cc/post/switch-on-strings-with-c11/).

Answer (score 0):

Como comenté en [esta otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/58716/a-qu%c3%a9-se-debe-este-error-error-switch-quantity-not-an-integer/58817#58817), la instrucción `switch` únicamente puede utilizarse con algunos tipos nativos... y un array de caracteres no es un tipo nativo.

Sin embargo hay formas de *simular* este comportamiento.

Puedes, como te ha comentado @Trauma, calcular un hash para cada cadena (el hash debe poder almacenarse en un tipo numérico básico de C++) y utilizar dicho hash para programar el `switch`. El problema que plantea esta solución es que únicamente obtendrías una solución *limpia* a partir del estándar C++17:

```
template<class LENGTH>
constexpr int GetHash(const wchar_t(&cadena)[LENGTH])
{
  // Calculo del hash
  // aqui no se puede usar ni memoria dinamica ni funciones no constexpr
}

int main()
{
  int i = 5;
  const wchar_t * cadena = /* ... */

  switch(GetHash(cadena))
  {
    case GetHash("OPCION1"):
      /* ... */
      break;

    case GetHash("OPCION2"):
      /* ... */
      break;

    // ...
  }
}
```

En versiones anteriores tendrías que *precalcular* el valor de los diferentes hashes.

Otra posibilidad es usar un mapa para que resuelva la operativa por nostros:

```
void func(const wchar_t* cadena)
{
  // Tambien se podria usar std::unordered_map
  static std::map<wchar_t*,int> tablaConversion;

  // Para rellenar la tabla (solo se ejecuta la primera vez)
  if( tablaConversion.empty() )
  {
    // Se rellena el mapa...
    tablaConversion.insert(std::make_pair(L"OPCION1",1));
    tablaConversion.insert( /* ... */ );
  }

  auto it = tablaConversion.find(cadena);
  if( it != tablaConversion.end() )
  {
    switch( it->second )
    {
      case 1: // OPCION1
        /* ... */
        break;

      // ...
    }
  }
  else
    // aqui el contenido de la etiqueta "default"
}
```

Esta última versión admitiría una vuelta de tuerca más y consistiría en que el propio mapa almacenase un puntero al código a ejecutar en cada caso:

```
void func(const wchar_t* cadena)
{
  // std::function disponible a partir de C++11
  static std::map<wchar_t*,std::function<void()> tablaConversion;

  // Para rellenar la tabla (solo se ejecuta la primera vez)
  if( tablaConversion.empty() )
  {
    // Se rellena el mapa...
    tablaConversion.insert(std::make_pair(L"OPCION1",[](){ std::cout << "1"; }));
    tablaConversion.insert( /* ... */ );
  }

  auto it = tablaConversion.find(cadena);
  if( it != tablaConversion.end() )
  {
    it->second(); // Ejecutamos el codigo correspondiente a la opcion elegida
  }
  else
    // el texto no se encuentra en el mapa
}
```

Habría formas más limpias de rellenar el mapa pero no están disponibles en todas las versiones de C++... lo dejo así porque creo que es más facil de entender para todos.

Y, para finalizar, siempre puedes sustituir el `switch` por una cadena de `if-else`.

Comment: ¿Parecido a lo que se hace en [esta pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40515/funci%c3%b3n-recursiva-constexpr-usando-if-constexpr-e-if-tradicional)!

Answer (score -1):

Como las opciones del switch deben ser del mismo tipo, te recomiendo que las pongas en constantes:

```
static const opcion1 *example=L"myprogram1";
static const opcion2 *example=L"myprogram2";

wchar_t var1 = ((LVITEMW*)lparam)->pszText;
switch ( var1 ) {
    case opcion1:
        return 1;
        break;
    case opcion2:
        return 2;
        break;
    default:     
        break;
}
```

Comment: En tu solución estarías comparando únicamente los punteros. No va a funcionar